# How to limit page pagination

Tags: pages

I'm looking for a way to show only 15 pages in a category. I have around 50 pages, but I don't want the old pages to be accessible. Only the first 15 pages. How to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to only show 15 posts per page, then only show the first page and pretend the others don't exist? Would it be easier if you asked "How do I flag a post so that it isn't listed in categories/archives?"

Comment: Hello sorry. My english is not very good. Yes I only want to show the first 15 pages, and the rest not available. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: Any reason not to delete the old posts/pages or change the the post status to draft?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.
I'm moving a 200k pages website to wordpress (don't ask me why... the client chose wp... he is the king)
Now that it's all up google crawls the 1000s of pages for each category.  Totally useless for SEO (indexing old articles on a news website) and this just drains the server in pointless loops.  Has anyone found a clean way for limiting categories pagination? (archive.php)