# How to modify query so it grabs only 90 posts in total?

Tags: wp-query

I want to have 3 Pages with 30 posts each: **Total 90 posts.**
**/page/4/ shouldn't exist**. Should either 404 or redirect to home.

Only /, /page/2/ and /page/3/ should exist.
With 30 posts each, like so:

- / *posts -> 01-30*
- /page/2/ *posts -> 31-60*
- /page/3/ *posts -> 61-90*

I've tried numerous suggestions, none limit the query for me. Just the number of posts per page. This looked promising but has no effect (/page/999/ works)

```
function wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    if ($query->is_front_page()) {
//this:
return '90';
//or even this: 
return 'LIMIT 90';
    }

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Some people as a work around suggest counting with PHP and using an if to stop showing the posts. That's a work around i want to limit the SQL query.

Comment: What problem does this solve for you? Can you provide some context?

Comment: @TomJNowell with 17,000 posts the home page main query is a slow query.

Comment: hmmm I don't think this will do much for your performance if you have a paginated homepage, what you're asking for is equivalent to just pretending there are only 3 pages. Keep in mind that some queries scale very well with post counts. Others scale catastrophically ( e.g. anything involving post meta, or `__not_in` style queries

Comment: I ended up leaving default behavior (all posts, 20 per page). But installed elasticsearch server with elasticpress plugin i can do " 'ep_integrate'   => true," and bypass mysql altogether. It's way faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `paginate_links( $args )`. Here is code adopted from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Example_With_a_Custom_Query).

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// the loop etc goes here.. 

$big = 999999999; 

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'       => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'     => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'    => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'prev_next'  => false,
    'total'      => 3
) );
```

See detail here on [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work because it is limiting the current loop to 90 records. **It doesn't limit the total records.**

For your problem, you can just cap the **paged** value before WordPress does its main loop like this.

```
function override_paged(){
    if(get_query_var('paged')>3){

        //Cap the value
        set_query_var( 'paged', 3 ); 

        //Or redirect
        //wp_safe_redirect('HOME_PAGE_URL');die();

    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','override_paged');
```

This **will affect** all WordPress query, so please adjust to your requirements.

Comment: Hi thanks. It does it but the pagination links underneath still show all the pages instead of just the 3, What can i do?

Comment: Solved with @Qaisar Feroz idea of using  'total'   => 3 on the pagination links. Else it would offer all the pages as options.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` takes a query object in as a parameter, it should be using that object to set query variables. That way it can also check if it's the homepage, and if it's the main query